# I am struggling to properly format my output from this nested for-loop

Tags: java

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
1 1 2

3 5 8

13 21 34
```

But my current output is: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34`

How should I approach the formatting?

```
rows = s.nextInt();
columns = s.nextInt();
int firstNumber = 0;
int secondNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        int f = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = f;

        System.out.printf(f + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input and how did you format your output?

Comment: Where is the nested for-loop you speak of?

Comment: Please show some code that is relevant to your question

Comment: I'm sorry! I edited the post just now to include it Also I'm aware that the actual numeric results don't match, but I just wanted to understand my formatting error better.

Comment: You are missing an extra check for when to print a newline. I posted an answer below showing an example for how to do that. For your updated code above, you should be able to do something similar to what I did: `if (....) { System.out.println(); }` – fill in the `if` check with something that makes sense for "every 3rd value".

Answer (score 1):

Just Call `println()` in outer loop (Which is for rows only).

```
rows = s.nextInt();
columns = s.nextInt();
int firstNumber = 0;
int secondNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        int f = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = f;
        System.out.printf(f + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how you could format that given set of data (if it were in an `int` array) with 3 values per line. The extra piece is that as `index` changes, I'm checking if it is evenly divisible by 3 – if you wanted to print 4 values per line, you could change it to be `index % 4`). If `index` is evenly divisible by 3, then it does `println()` which includes a newline. Otherwise, it just does `print()` with whatever number is at `numbers[index]`.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34};
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
    if (index % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(numbers[index] + " ");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1 1 2 
3 5 8 
13 21 34
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
    public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows = s.nextInt();
int columns = s.nextInt();
int firstNumber = 0;
int secondNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        int f = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = f;

        System.out.printf(f + " ");

    } 
         System.out.printf(" \n");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf(" \n");`  for new line which is executed after each row.